# ¿Cómo obtener funciones de un .php de manera remota?

Tags: php

Hay forma de hacer que obtenga las funciones a partir de un archivo remoto?

Ejemplo:

Tengo este archivo llamado "funciones.php" en mi servidor:

```
<?php
    function redirect($url, $code = 303)
    {
       header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
       die();
    }
?>
```

Y deseo incluirlo en un archivo local:

```
<?php
    include 'http://example.com/funciones.php';
    redirect("example.com");
?>
```

Pero esto hacerlo sin activar `allow_url_include` en php.ini, ¿Hay forma alguna?

Gracias.

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta aceptada puede ser tu solución: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358207/curl-alternative-to-require-a-file-instead-of-allow-url-fopen

Comment: @Error404 Si, era lo que estaba buscando, entiendo la ideologia del sistema, pero no logro obtener los datos, estos se quedan en blanco. Hice un echo en mi archivo local. Averigue que obtengo este error en el archivo remoto: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Comment: Sinceramente no he usado nunca curl, por eso simplemente te puse el link por si te podía ayudar ya que yo no podría dar una explicación consistente sobre él (prefiero no hablar de temas que desconozco). Sin embargo, el error que te da parece claro, la función `call_user_func_array()` necesita dos parámetros y el segundo tiene que ser un array. En cambio, tu le estás pasando un número null.

Comment: La respuesta es **no**. ¿El motivo? La **seguridad**. Imagina que alguien pueda usar esta técnica para incluir el archivo de conexión a la base de datos  en el cual almacenas tus credenciales de conexión. Y luego hace un `echo $usuario;  echo $password; echo $lo_que_sea;` ¿te imaginas eso?

Answer (score 1):

Imaginate que si cualquier persona pudiera incluir archivos PHP de forma remota podria tener acceso al codigo fuente de cualquier proyecto.

Al hacer una peticion remota de un archivo PHP el servidor web (http://example.com) esta procesando ese archivo PHP y solo estarias incluyendo la respuesta de ese script. La unica forma de incluir el codigo fuente seria teniendo acceso al servidor web donde esta alojado funciones.php y o bien renombrando el archivo utilizando una extension que no este configurada para ser procesada por el parser de PHP (dll, data, etc) o modificar las directivas del servidor para que no procese archivos con extension PHP.

Despues de esto deberias incluir el archivo remoto en tu script. Cabe aclarar que exponer codigo fuente en un servidor es muy riesgoso.